# Django - Admin page login also logged into user authentication

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

After I logged in to admin page, my site also logged in by superuser. And when I logged out from it also logged out from admin. Please help me.

Comment: Your question is unclear please elaborate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but it sounds like expected behavior.

Comment: First I logged in to my admin page. After that, I visit my website. But it's authenticated by superuser. How is it possible?

Comment: Which admin page do you visit? The admin page of your website or some other website's admin page?

Comment: My admin page. Brother.

Comment: In that case I fear I don't understand the question. Why would you expect a different behavior? Once you log in with a different account your browser will store a different sessionid cookie for that domain. The next time you visit a different part of your website (whether it's the django admin or some other page) you will send the new sessionid cookie and thus have the privileges of the account you last logged in with.